# Identifying if a column is in descending order

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Management Studio. I am a bit new so I hope I am not breaking any rules. My data is 15 columns and almost a million rows, however I am just giving you a sample to get assistance on one area where I am stuck.

In the above example as you can see the column 'lastlevel' values are decreasing.  Also you can see that data in the 'Last_read' column date range is from today to 14 days prior (it was ran yesterday hence April 27, also pls. disregard that for 1st customer date 2021/04/14 is missing, it is an anomaly).
Column 'Shipto' provides the customer number and each customer has max 14 rows of data.

Please disregard column 'current_reading' and rn

If look at 'lastlevel' again you will notice that the values are going down consistently, however on April 18th, it goes from 0.73 to 0.74, showing an increase of 0.01.

What I want to do is that whenever there is an increase at all, I want that whole customer's all 14 rows be removed from the output i.e. I only want to see customers that have the prefect descending data and no increases.

Can you help?

Comment: NOTE: Your rows 2 and 3 can legitimately be reversed and still be in time order *(because `last_read` is the same for both rows)*.  Either you need values with TIME components, or another column to order by As Well As the `last_read`.

Comment: yes I just noticed that there is a date duplication

Comment: Which may also be why you SAY there are 14 rows per customer, but your example has 16 rows per customer.

Comment: So, first of all, the example you provided has 16 observations over 14 days... how do you know how to order the two entries on April 14; did lastlevel go up or down? Is Last_read really a datetime field and you're not displaying the time part? Remember that database tables have no natural "order", the data must provide the means to order it unambiguously. Once you can provide an unambiguous ordering of the records then we can help you with your query.

Comment: yeah, so another problem, I ran your query and it gave me an error saying 'Lag' is not a recongnized built in function, i entered SELECT @@version and it gave me Micorsoft SQL Server 2005!

Comment: SQL Server 2005 reached End Of Life in 2016.  That means you're no longer getting security updates, etc.  You may have bigger problems than a SQL Query.  Also, the answer without `LAG()` is very long winded and I'm typing this all on my phone, so I won't be giving a 2005 answer.  Maybe you'll get better traction if you open another question and tag it with the specific SQL Server Version you're using.

Comment: What's the primary key of the table?

Comment: shipto - again it is sql server 2005 @NicholasHunter

Comment: The primary key can't be shipto because shipto is not unique.

Comment: i don't have a unique Id in my query

Comment: Does your _table_ have a _primary key_? If so, what is it? Also, what is the data type of the _last_read_ column?

Comment: I don't have a primary key, and data type is convert(varchar(10), b.Last_Read,111)

Comment: In SSMS, please type EXEC sp_help (your table name) and paste the result as text into your question.

Comment: I have updated the write up and data, hopefully someone can assist me

Comment: Whatever you changed was not salient to the problem. Without knowing more about the underlying table structure, it is very difficult to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  deltas AS
(
  -- For each [Shipto]; deduct the preceding row's value and record it as the [delta]
  -- Note, each [Shipto]'s first row's delta with therefor be NULL
  SELECT
    *,
    lastlevel - LAG(lastlevel) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipto ORDER BY Last_Read, lastlevel DESC)  AS delta
  FROM
    yourTable
),
  max_deltas AS
(
  -- Get the maximum of the deltas per [Shipto]
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(delta) OVER (PARTITION BY Shipto) AS max_delta
  FROM
    deltas
)
-- Return only rows where the delta never exceeds 0 (thus, never ascending over any timestep)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  max_deltas
WHERE
  max_delta <= 0
```

I've ordered by `Last_Read, lastlevel DESC` such that if two readings are on the same date, it is assumed that the highest value should be considered to have happened first.